# UICollectionView cells out of bounds

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

How can I force the `uicollectionview` to not hide the cells when scrolled out of bound (the boundaries are smaller the the container view's). Here is a little video about the my problem: http://youtu.be/pglO5s8MZqk .

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Did you ever solve this?